# How to move Project from one Subversion Repository to another?

Tags: svn, repository

I'm trying to write a script that will copy a number of projects from one (internal) Subversion repository to another (external) Subversion repository. I have tried and failed to use svnadmin dump in conjunction with svndumpfilter and I keep coming across issues regarding files that have moved and the original location no longer exists. I have tried using svndumpfilter2 and svndumpfilter3 but a variety of errors have prevented me from pursuing this route.

Since it is **not** necessary to preserve the history of the changes I thought a simple script would suffice. I simply check out a project from the old repository, use switch to update the repository and then perform an update. However I simply get an error stating the UUID of the new repository is invalid:

*svn: The repository at 'file:///home/developer/svn/NEW_REPO/java/jar/FOO' has uuid 'c315c701-d367-47aa-a473-87f95147eb5f', but the WC has '8ce3ae18-f586-4a38-8bf8-e0fc691799fb'*

Here is my script:

```
svn checkout file:////home/developer/svn/OLD_REPO/java/jar/FOO
cd FOO
svn switch --relocate file:////home/developer/svn/OLD_REPO/java/jar/FOO file:////home/developer/svn/NEW_REPO/java/jar/FOO .
svn update
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong or is switch not suited to this task?

***UPDATE***

I have moved this forward. The UUID issue was with how I created the target repository. I have since run

```
svnadmin setuuid file:////home/developer/svn/NEW_REPO <old_repo_id>
```

And now I don't get the UUID issue. However I instead get the issue:

**svn: Cannot replace a directory from within**

I don't understand why. Trying to update the project from outside of the directory doesn't work either.

***UPDATE***

Following a suggestion I have switched my script to now use import and export and this works for the time when my "to repository" is empty. My script does not work a subsequent time. Can anyone help. Script is now:

```
# Create a list of projects to Update
echo java/pom/FOO > list.txt;
echo java/jar/FOO2 >> list.txt;
echo java/jar/FOO2 >> list.txt;

for project in `cat list.txt`; do
    echo "Updating: "${project};
    projName=`echo ${project} | awk -F"/" '{print $NF}'`

    # Obtain the current version 
    svn export ${FROM_REPO}${project} ${projName}
    # Remove the .svn information
    find ${projName} -name .svn -exec rm -rf {} \;
    # Import the project into the new repository
    svn import -m 'Updated by script' ${projName} ${TO_REPO}${project}
    rm -rf ${projName}
done;
```

Comment: 1. Exported tree is **unversioned data**, it doesn't contain any metadata in .svn-dir (and .svn also) 2. Import (AFAICR) is one-time action for empty repository

Comment: Why you don't use ol'good svnsync?

Comment: Lazy Badger, we decided against SvnSync since we want to decide when we push the release the the New Repository. Also we don't care about comments / history from the original repository.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `svn export`, you don't have to remove the `.svn` directories.

I've done this many a times. The program itself is fairly simply, but it does require several passes:

#### First Pass: `find $from -type d`

- If you find a directory in your `$from` that's not in the `$to`, do an `svn add`.
- If both the `$from` and the `$to` have that directory, go to the next.

#### Second Pass: `find $to`

- If your `$to` has a directory or file that doesn't exist in your `$from`, do an `svn delete` on that file or directory.

#### Third Pass: `find $from -type d`:

- If the file exists in both `$from` and `$to`, copy the file from `$from` to `$to`.
- If the file exists in the `$from` but not the `$to`, copy the file `$from` to `$to` and do an `svn add` on that file.

You can do something like this for your loops:

```
find `$to` -type -d | while read $directory
do
     blah, blah, blah
done
```

Comment: Crikey, that is more complicated than I expected it to be. I wanted to check out (some) projects from my old Repository, modify their SVN information so it points point to the new Repository and the commit.

I'll follow your advice and try to build a script following your logic. I'll post the results here.

Comment: It isn't all that complicated. It just takes a couple of passes. You want to make sure that directories exist before files (first pass), then add the files that are new or modified, (second pass), then make sure that things that are deleted are no longer in the repository.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is move the HEAD revision of a project (I'm assuming it's contained in a single directory) from one svn repository to another, probably the most straightforward method would be to [svn export](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.export.html) it from the original location (to a local directory), then [svn import](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.import.html) it to the new location.

Comment: Stuart, I've followed your suggestion and have now got a script that can do the initial copy into an empty new repository. Hurrah! However, it only works one. An import cannot commit if the target is already there. I'll update my question with my latest script. Can you help to make it runnable more than once?

Comment: I don't follow you.  Of course the script wouldn't work twice on the same "project", because you'd be trying to import something that you've already imported.  If you are talking about importing a *different* project, you need to make sure you are importing it to a different location (folder) in the new svn repository.  Let me know if I am missing something here.

Comment: Are you saying that you can't run the entire *script* multiple times?  That would be expected.  Or is it that it only works for the first ${project}?

Comment: I guess I'm getting confused with svn imports (adding something to a repository for the first time) and svn commit ??? (just updating something). My script works the import of each project but of course won't update a change (sorry, my svn-foo is weak - I've always used GUIs before. )

Comment: Correct -- svn import is used to push files to a new repository directory from outside a working copy.  It will not do anything if the repository directory already exists.  You need to use svn commit to push changes from a working copy to its already-existing "backing" repository location.

Answer (score 0):

With Mercurial+HGSubversion (and some black-magic in the middle) your process will be just

```
hg pull OLD_REPO
hg push NEW_REPO
```